# What is the difference between "super" and "superb"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

I have seen usage of both **super** and **superb**.

I also searched for meaning of these two words and found they are almost identical.

**Example sentences -**

1. She is a **super** girl.
2. His performance in the last game was **superb**.

Use of any of those two words doesn't change the meaning of those above sentences either.

Need suggestion of proper usage of these two words. When to use and why?

Comment: Etymologically, *super* comes from the Latin preposition meaning *over, above, atop* and *superb* comes from the Latin adjective *superbus* meaning *grand, proud; haughty, supercilious*.  The latter obviously comes from the former.  In English, *super* tends to be a general intensifier and *superb* an adjective denoting high quality.

Comment: Are you serious? Why don't they call the character Superbman, rather than Superman. Environmental disaster superfund vs superbfund.

Comment: Note that it would be perfectly normal to say "she is a superb girl" or "his performance was super!"

Comment: @BlessedGeek exactly! That's also my question. If you have an answer why don't you post?

Answer (score 4):

*Superb* refers to excellence (the best) whereas *super* refers to something above normal, like size or effort, but not necessarily something excellent.

So *super* man is not by definition a *superb* man.